# sbt: selecting main class for running

Tags: scala, sbt

I have ~6 main classes in my application, by I usually use only one of them, so I wanted to run it automatically by sbt. sbt makes it possible to define two keys in build.sbt:

```
// Run Key
val selectMainClass = TaskKey[Option[String]]("select-main-class", "Selects the main class to run.")
val mainClass = TaskKey[Option[String]]("main-class", "Defines the main class for packaging or running.")
```

so I defined them (sample project, two classes - Main1 & Main2 in the root of source dir):

```
mainClass := Some("Main1")

selectMainClass := Some("Main1")
```

And `show main-class' from sbt prompt also seems to work:

```
[info] Some(Main1)
```

But sbt's `run` task still prompts me for main class.

Also, [sbt-revolver](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver) fails to work with multiple classes with exception `java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get`

Using sbt 0.11.2.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you can see from using *inspect*, *mainClass* is scoped to various configurations and tasks:

```
> inspect compile:main-class(for run)
[info] Task: scala.Option[java.lang.String]
[info] Description:
[info]  Defines the main class for packaging or running.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/heiko/tmp/}default-d7f1bf/compile:main-class(for run)
...
```

Therefore you have to use proper scoping:

```
set mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("Foo")
```

Answer (score 22):

To prevent this:

```
sbt> ~run

Multiple main classes detected, select one to run:

[1] com.yourapp.MainClass1
[2] com.yourapp.MainClass2
[3] com.yourapp.MainClass3
```

do this:

```
sbt> ~runMain com.yourapp.MainClass1
```

Comment: All I wanted was to run from SBT and it quickly solved the issue. thanks

Answer (score 6):

If you want to specify a main class for revolver specifically:

```
set mainClass in Revolver.reStart := Some("some.package.mainClass")
```

Comment: What would be the equivalent way/syntax of defining this inside build.sbt?

Comment: @matt mainClass in Revolver.reStart := Some("some.package.mainClass")

Comment: Actually I switched to regular `~run` which runs my app inside the same JVM as SBT not as a separate one... will give this a try.. hope revolver is still working with new Scala versions

Answer (score 4):

oneline console:

```
sbt "run-main com.path.to.MainClass"
```