# How do I run a main class from build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

Given a subproject, how do I run a main class of that project as a dependency of another subproject?

Comment: You want the result of `Main` to be a dependency of the sub project?

Comment: Yes, but the subproject isn't a scala project. the `Main` generates code for that project.

Comment: Ee... Sounds nasty :X

Comment: Shouldn't be as bad as it sounds.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your sbt

```
// set the main class for 'sbt run'
mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("com.Foo")
```

Or this from cmd:

```
$ sbt "run-main com.Foo"
```

Comment: No interested in how to run it from shell, I'm interested in how to do it from within an sbt Task.

Comment: Maybe it can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612614/sbt-selecting-main-class-for-running